# Android SoftKeyboard

Tags: android, opengl-es, keyboard

Hey there, I was wondering if it is possible to use the Android SoftKeyboard within an OpenGL rendered Application (Game)?

I ask this, because I want to have an ingame gui with self rendered text input fields and ofc with support of the soft keyboard. Is this possible or do I have to render the keyboard all by myself ? (This would be quite a hassle...)

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Mfg Imp

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there are no problems with using the softkeyboard with GLSurfaceView. Look to the [InputMethodManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html) class for methods to show and hide the keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.  You will have to make the keyboard background transparent, and I would suggest making the keys semi-transparent as well, so it does not cover whatever graphics are shown on the surfaceview.

You can modify the softkeyboard sample "input.xml" file as follows:

```
<com.example.android.softkeyboard.LatinKeyboardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/keyboard"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:keyBackground="@android:color/transparent"
    />
```